# Leer un array de objetos con jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

uso este codigo Jquery para  hacer llamado aun array json

```
   $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/categorias.ajax.php",
                method: "POST",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,                    
                data: datos,

                success: function(respuesta){
  
                    $("#txtTitulo").val("respuesta['titulo']");
                    $("#txtUrl").val(respuesta['url']);
                    $("#txtGenero").val(respuesta.['genero']);

                }      
        });
```

el Json

```
[{"id":1,"0":1,"titulo":"Prueba 01","1":"Prueba 01","url":"prueba-01","2":"prueba-01","fecha":422637810,"3":422637810,"status":"1","4":"1","acciones":"X","8":"X"}]
```

Pero no aparece nada en mi tabla y ya no se que puedo editar.
Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Prueba con `val(respuesta[0].titulo);` etc

Comment: No me funciona tampoco pero al poner un valor cualquiera como .val("prueba") si se puede ver en mi tabla.

Comment: Pues a mi si me funciona con tu json.  Míralo en [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/hbfdo10y/1/)

Comment: Si funciona este codigo solo que debia colocar esta linea  dataType: "json", Saludos